# Opera crash if prompt box pops when in another tab

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, opera

Opera Version:63.0.3368.43 I am currently working with Websockets to catch all the phone calls incoming (events). Every event return JSON. After every hangup event, a prompt box shows to ask the user to insert the file number of the caller. If you stay on the same tab the prompt box shows and there is no problem. If you go to another tab and there is a hangup event, the prompt doesn't show and the page goes full white if you try to refresh the page Opera crashes and reloads all the pages. It's working on Chrome and Safari. I haven't tried on FF yet. Is it a bug they need to fix? Where can I find any logs of the crash?

Here is some code but I don't think it will help.

```
if (event.event == "Hangup") {
      var dossier = window.prompt("Entrez le numero de dossier : ", "96376");

      if (event.callfilename != null) {
        var callfilename = event.callfilename;
      }

      if (dossier != null) {
        window.location.href = "XXXXX?d=" + dossier + "&ext=" + poste + "&f=" + callfilename;
      } else {
        window.location.href = "XXXXX?ext=" + poste + "&f=" + callfilename;
      }
 }
```

I want to be able to navigate to other tabs and that the prompt box still shows on the first tab waiting for input.

**UPDATE :** I solved the problem creating custom modal boxes

Comment: what is the API you are using for phone calls ?

Comment: Im using a custom API provided by another company. I think the problem is with Opera since its working with every other browser. It seems that the browser crashes when a prompt box is shown when in another tab. I tried disabling the built-in ad-blocker, and every other extensions.

Comment: Opera DOES use a customized Blink build, but its mostly equal to Chromium/Chrome baseline. When you say "custom API" - do you just mean a library ? Maybe that library has a bug ? If it not a secret - posting that library name might be a good help to people who will try to answer your question.